# Do you install your domain DLLs in GAC?

Tags: .net

I've been a ASP.NET/WCF developer for most of my .NET developer career so I'm very used to the idea of just having all DLLs sitting in the bin folder of the IIS directory.

However, in a recent project we have to share several DLLs (around 50) between a WCF web service and several .exe programs so one of our team member suggested that we can install these DLLs into the GAC.

I can't see anything wrong with this idea but I just have a feeling that installing domain DLLs such as data access and business logic for a specific product into GAC is wrong because these DLLs are not like System.Data, which is reusable across many different products.

Do you install your product's DLLs into GAC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Warning, this is a holy war area*

I have seen it both ways, if a DLL is shared we generally GAC it( that's our simple rule of thumb ).  Basically we dont want multiple occurrences of the same DLL laying around.  However, we bypass this rule if the library is unstable aka constantly undergoing changes/new versions.

Some people argue it is better to silo yourself (place in bin), to prevent someone from reinstalling a gac'd dll that could potentially crash your app.  In general, whenever you use a shared library, you need to take care when making changes.  If you are going to break someone else, you probably want to think about incrementing the version.  Then you can deploy both versions to the GAC.

Another argument against placing bin is if you want to install a new version, you have to place it in N different locations.

My bias shows through my answer(I prefer gac over duplication)

Comment: Ups, I read your warning too late :-) But is it really? For example most library vendedors (like Telerik, DevExpress) simply copy their assemblies on your bin folder, so it seems to me that most people avoid the GAC (unless forced like in COM+ interop).

Comment: Most people is a pretty generic statement.  Enterprise Library is a classic example of a thing we GAC'd.  Why duplicate all of the dlls everywhere?  You are also talking about development, which is a lot different then packaging for production deployments.

Comment: Granted, my "most people" statement is questionable, at least. OTOH EntLib is infraestructure code, and I was trying to make my case on business apps code.

Comment: GAC'ing visual tool libraries makes sense for most vendors, it makes it easier to auto-register to the VS toolbox.  But for anyone who's had to patch these 3rd party libraries (SyncFusion, cough cough), what a PITA it is to uninstall the original DLLS (and there will be many of these!) from the GAC and to install the new DLLs into the GAC...

Comment: @Edgar Sánchez for "business apps code" wouldn't Business Logic be the same for all parties that are using it ( thus justifying gac'ing it assuming its shared amoung projects)

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time we don't put application .DLLs on the GAC, this leads to some duplication but, overtime, simplifies problems as versioning (the more apps you have, the more they will evolve at different speeds) which are harder than wasting some (cheap) disk space.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather keep them in bin folder - xcopy deployment is much easier.

Answer (score -1):

Deploying to the GAC is a nightmare if you need to update the DLLs that you placed there. Whatever goes into the GAC should be ***fairly static,*** versionable content.  Otherwise, **do not place into the GAC**.

An alternate approach might be to host the shared DLLs on 1) a secured, intranet web server or  2) a commonly accessible network folder, and use the [AssemblyResolve (MSDN link here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) approach to load them.  We do that at our current project and it has been very, very effective.

Comment: Just give the updated assembly a different version number.  Not sure why that's a nightmare, it's what you are supposed to do.

Comment: @Hans: sure, update the assembly version number, and then deploy to 1,000+ workstations.  Not a small job.  In fact, a veritable deployment nightmare when everything is considered.  That's why we need ClickOnce or something like a shared folder approach.

Comment: Well, I don't disagree, nice when programs are smart enough to update themselves.  Maybe I'm moving in the wrong circles though, I don't see a lot of IT staff that chooses pull over push.  They don't like 1000+ workstations going down at the same time.  It's an option that the OP doesn't seem to consider either, maybe you should mention it in your answer.